Replying to Discord Webhooks with a Discord Bot
I have a webhook that posts a message in a channel from a google forms page. What I am trying to do, is create some buttons that will populate once the webhook has come in that will essentially say paid/denied. At present I am not concerned about responding to the message itself but more with getting the buttons to populate at all.
This is the code I have so far that does not work.
client.on('messagecreate', (Message)=>
{
    if(Message.author.bot)
    {
        const expenseSuccess = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setLabel('Paid')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Succes)
        .setCustomId('expenseSuccess');

        const expenseFail = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setLabel('Denied')
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
        .setCustomId('expenseFail');

        const buttonRow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(expenseSuccess, expenseFail);
        Message.reply({content: 'Please Select...', components: [buttonRow] });
    } 
    else{
        return;
    }
});


What about the code does not work? What do you expect to happen versus what is actually happening?

So at present when i run the code no buttons appear in discord when the webhook triggers. I'm not sure what exactly is causing it not to run. Basically I want the Bot to recognise the webhook has triggered and left a message and then leave buttons underneath the message.

@JohnBrinken I assume this is being written with NodeJS. What's the name of the package that you're using for interacting with Discord? It'd be useful to mention that in your question so other users can have a look at the documentation to see if we can help.

@CrazyRedd Please excuse my ignorance this is my first time working with JS at all. I am using NodeJS and specifically Discord.JS.
